# unity wikitude error? not running in android phone?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, wikitude, wikitude-sdk

when I try to run sample project of Wikitude on an android phone it keeps showing **"Running without platform assisted tracking support"** what does that mean? I am new to AR so I don't have much idea about this.

[screen shot of androidapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYmqZ.jpg)

Comment: Please provide the important/failing part of your code.

Comment: everything imported perfectly but when I run it  shows  instead of opening a camera it shows Running without platform assisted tracking support.   I attached a screenshot of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikitude SDK 7.2.0 added support for ARKit and ARCore to be used when running instant tracking. The message you are seeing is meant to inform you that ARKit / ARCore is not running, most likely because the device you are running on doesn't support it.

For more information about this topic, you can check the Wikitude [documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/unity/instanttrackingnative.html#smart-seamless-ar-tracking).

If the camera is not running, please try to disable the Multithreaded Rendering option in Unity.